# Abandoment to blame for the last JavaScript file not always being loaded?

Tags: web-development, javascript, analytics

I have a code snippet for an app that users are loading as a 3rd party script on their site.  The general sequence is as follows:

1. Site loads `http://www.example.com/foo.js`
2. `foo.js` does stuff
3. 1 to 2 seconds later, `foo.js` loads `bar.js`

Now in a perfect world, I'd want to see matching counts for the calls to `foo.js` and `bar.js`.  However, `bar.js` loads only about 94% of the time.  I'm wondering how much of this discrepancy might be attributable to site abandonment given the fact that `bar.js` is delayed by 1 or 2 seconds.

I posted here instead of StackOverflow since I *think* it's more a question about what would be typical time on page when users abandon the page.

Answer (score 1):

Some percentage of this is probably browsers that don't support JavaScript or just have JavaScript disabled.

Web crawlers would never hit `bar.js` for instance... (although most of them would probably have also skipped `foo.js` too...)

Answer (score 1):

- Some users probably click away before the page fully loads
- Some users have connection problems for the second request
- Browsers without JS support or with JS disabled
- Maybe security settings? These files are both being loaded from he same domain right?
- Maybe there's a bug in the JS that's preventing some browsers from loading the second file. Is there a correlation with browser type/version?
- Web spiders